# calling github api doesn't return thing

Tags: php

Calling GitHub API route like this

```
$url='https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=2021-3-1&sort=stars&order=desc';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

but when I try `var_dump($content);die();` th result in browser

> bool(false)

Comment: Try with curl and a user agent string, because it works in a browser.

Comment: I used curl but also it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because GitHub expects you to set a User-Agent header, so you need to create a proper context for `file_get_contents`:

```
$url  = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=2021-3-1&sort=stars&order=desc';
$opts = [

  'http' => [
      
      'method'  => 'GET',
      'header'  => 'User-Agent: MyAgent/1.0',
    ]
];

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result   = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: ok now there is aresult but it is n't injson form that I can access and read its content

Comment: Response (at least with the given URL) is proper JSON, so you just need to: `json_decode($result, true)` to get an array and loop over it - if that's what you want, that is.

Comment: I used json_decode but it doesn't return result in friendly way you can try the url in browser and in php code you will see the difference

Comment: The data returned is exactly the same in both cases - both the browser and the script return an identical JSON response, which you can further process to meet your needs. The point & click experience given to you by e.g. Firefox when displaying JSON data is a browser feature you'll have to implement yourself in the context of your script/application (using JavaScript) . Or you'll just ```file_put_contents()``` the raw data (i.e., without decoding it), and open the resulting file with Firefox afterwards if you just want a quick review of the data.

Comment: bro I need the returned result from this url to be converted to array that is readable and I can loop on it but this not happen when I dumb the result from json decode I have long strings and gui button images like github page with links .

Comment: As I said above, ```json_decode($result, true)``` turns the result into an array - which is iterable.  Go ahead and see for yourself: https://phpsandbox.io/n/polished-wind-moek-noksz

Comment: BTW: Since my answer solved your _initial_ problem it would be nice if you consider accepting it.

Comment: I accepted it and mark it as useful thanks bro .